# Is it correct to use “increasing” in this context?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I want to use this sentence in my paper. Is it correct grammatically?

> Microaggregation, as a Statistical Disclosure Control (SDC) method, provides lower Disclosure Risk (DR) at the expense of increasing Information Loss (IL).

I’m not sure about the word “*increasing*”.

Comment: "at the risk of **increased** Information Loss (IL)", not *increasing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's perfectly correct if you mean it causes more loss of information.

Comment: The reference is to an object (*IL*), not an action (*increase*) -- the risk is of (an) **increased** Information Loss.

Comment: No, it is correct. "It provides so and so at the risk of increasing blah blah." The sentence talks about one action causing a negative counter-action. If it talked about a disadvantage that was already there (information loss) then it would be phrased like "provides lower DR in spite of IL".

Comment: I believe the confusion here comes from a tricky construction, and in order to see the _real_ parallel it is necessary to break the meaning down into what is _actually_ being said. The _true_ meaning of the sentence is this: "This fancy thing we do LOWERS _Disclosure Risk_ but unfortunately INCREASES _Information Loss_." And that's why when you put it back into its pompous syntax, *increasing* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think following should be correct (since loss is being compared in the sentence)

greater information loss

Answer (score 0):

*Increasing* is grammatically valid, but I agree with majority usage; *increased* is a better choice...

> Provides X, but *at the expense of **increased*** Y [(18,900 hits in Google Books)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22at%20the%20expense%20of%20increasing%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22but%20at%20the%20expense%20of%20increased%22&oq=%22but%20at%20the%20expense%20of%20increased%22&gs_l=serp.3...92890.93606.1.93862.4.4.0.0.0.0.94.306.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.wnIEBzet_0A&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.d2k&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1270&bih=930)
>    Provides X, but *at the expense of **increasing*** Y [(7,280 hits)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22at%20the%20expense%20of%20increasing%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22but%20at%20the%20expense%20of%20increasing%22&oq=%22but%20at%20the%20expense%20of%20increasing%22&gs_l=serp.3...3924.4805.2.5289.5.5.0.0.0.0.98.375.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.F9P0IN36kdQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.d2k&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1270&bih=930)